# split ajax response in two different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax code like this:

```
$j(document).ready(function () {

    function loading_show() {
        $j('#loading').html("<img src='images/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
    }

    function loading_hide() {
        $j('#loading').fadeOut();
    }

    function loadData(page) {
        loading_show();
        $j.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "load_data.php",
            data: "page=" + page,
            success: function (msg) {
                var $response = $j(msg);

                // Query the jQuery object for the values
                oGlobal = $response.filter('#Z').text();

                $j("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
                    loading_hide();
                    $j("#container").html(msg);
                });
            }
        });
    }

    loadData(1); // For first time page load default results

    $j('#container .pagination li.active').live('click', function () {
        var page = $j(this).attr('p');
        loadData(page);
    });
});
```

Im getting this response:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="Z">JuanFernando</div>
    <div id="q">
        <div class="pagination">
            <ul>
                <li p="1" class="inactive">First</li>
                <li class="inactive">Previous</li>
                <li p="1" style="color:#fff;background-color:#006699;" class="active">1</li>
                <li p="2" class="active">2</li>
                <li p="2" class="active">Next</li>
                <li p="2" class="active">Last</li>
            </ul>
            <input class="goto" size="1" style="margin-top:-1px;margin-left:60px;"
                type="text">
            <input id="go_btn" class="go_button" value="Go" type="button"><span class="total" a="2">Page <b>1</b> of <b>2</b></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to extract "JuanFernando" in order to show in div container but alone and I want that the rest of the response could be show in other different div for example: container2.

Comment: Can you change the response you're getting? Ideally you would get a json object with seperated data.

Comment: no, I can't change the response in json or other.

Comment: Oh I see now what the problem is... at first the HTML was not formatted by SO... it's clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ajaxComplete is not what you want to use here, especially inside your success function. You want your success function to look something like this:

```
success: function (msg) {
    loading_hide();
    var $response = $j(msg);

    // Query the jQuery object for the values
    oGlobal = $response.find('#Z').text();

    $j("#container").html(oGlobal);

    $response.find('#Z').remove();
    $j('<div id="container2"></div>').html($response.html()).appendTo('body');
}
```

We're just taking the `oGlobal` (which should be JuanFernando in this case) and sticking it in the `#container`. After that, remove the `#Z` div from the response, and stick the rest inside of a new `#container2`, and append it to the body, or wherever you'd like it.

Comment: the first part works great (the z content) but I cant do the second (the rest of content in other div) can you give me a hand?

Comment: the last line should insert the remaining content into whatever you put inside the `appendTo()` function. Here's a jsFiddle that puts the rest of the content into a `#b` div that exists already in the HTML. http://jsfiddle.net/HCVSF/1/

Answer (score 0):

[Here's an "adapted" fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/RZ8UQ/1/)

Basically the only thing that changes with you code is

replace

```
oGlobal = $response.filter('#Z').text();
```

with

```
oGlobal = $response.find('#Z').text();
```

also, see MattDiamant's answer concerning `ajaxComplete`.

Comment: Do you only want the text JuanFernando or the whole element?